# How to Use Bootstrap with Drop Down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, form-control

The drop down form shows up on the page, but the categories are just awkwardly floating below it and clicking on the drop down form does nothing. If I take out the  bootstrap form the drop down form then works perfectly, but it is an ugly default version.

**_form.html.erb**

```html
<form>
    <select class="form-control">
    <%= f.collection_select :categories, Value::VALUES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Choose Category' %>
  </select>
</form>
```

**value.rb model**

```
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    VALUES = ['Courage', 'Determination', 'Gratitude', 'Humor']

end
```

**The whole form**

```html
<%= form_for(@value) do |f| %>
  <% if @value.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@value.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this value from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @value.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="america">
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Value' %>
  </div>
  <select class="form-control">
    <%= f.collection_select :categories, Value::VALUES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Choose Category' %>
  </select>


  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to values_path, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to @value, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
  </form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't understand your code, you have a bunch of `form` tags, instead of just one. I'm guessing the problem is in `<select class="form-control">`, you shouldn't need it. Instead, I would try something like `<%= f.collection_select :categories, Value::VALUES, :to_s, :to_s, { :include_blank => true }, {class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Choose Category'} %>`. I'm guessing rails is confused about which are options and which are html_options, so the `{}`s should clarify that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you ptd

```html
<%= f.collection_select :categories, Value::VALUES, :to_s, :to_s, { :include_blank => true }, {class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Choose Category'} %>
```